# Copy a repeated group of lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to copy or extract a repeated group of lines in notepad++?

For example we have the following group which is 23 lines,

```
 GPU1        GPU2        GPU3        GPU4        GPU5        GPU6        GPU7        GPU8        GPU9    

180.0       0.000       180.0       0.000       0.000       0.000       180.0       180.0      2.4983E-06
```

Desired Output - 23 lines something like this
GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    GPU4
180.0   0.000   180.0   0.000

This is repeated for 109 groups in the file.
I realise this is an awkward request but worth a shot!

Thanks!

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59754058/edit) and add sample lines and expected result.

Comment: vim can do this trivially using visual mode and yank, fyi

Comment: What do you mean with :`we have the following group which is 23 lines,`? The given example has only 2 lines.

Comment: Do you want to keep only 4 columns on each line? That's not really clear. Please, give more input lines and expected result, and the rules used to do the match.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate the rules further. Apologies for the dodgy question!